# MVC: Ошибка авторизации

Tags: asp.net-mvc, auth

**Добрый день.**

Изучаю авторизацию на сайте (проект ASP MVC), и получаю ошибку:

> Для вызова этого метода свойство "Membership.Provider" должно быть
>   экземпляром "ExtendedMembershipProvider"

**Место ошибки:**

```
  [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Попытка создать пользователя.
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password); // !!! Ошибка
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("List", "Job");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "[Register]" +  (e.StatusCode.ToString()));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Я даже вручную скопировал библиотеки WebMatrix.Data.dll и WebMatrix.WebData.dll в проект в папку bin проекта.

**Как можно упразднить эту ошибку?**

Спасибо